# Can @GenerateValue be used with non primary key attributes?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am confused as everywhere it is  mentioned to use `@GenerateValue` only with `@Id`.

But: can it be used with non primary key attributes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [JPA specification document](https://github.com/javaee/jpa-spec/blob/master/jsr338-MR/JavaPersistence.pdf) provides an important hint that you should **not** do so, see section 11.1.20, on page 449:

> Footnote [110]: Portable applications should **not** use the GeneratedValue annotation on other persistent fields or properties.

Here, ”other“ refers to fields or properties of an Entity that are not annotated with `@Id`:

> The `GeneratedValue` annotation may be applied to a primary key property or field of an entity or mapped superclass **in conjunction** with the `Id` annotation.

Hence, I would conclude that most, if not all,  *persistence provider* implementations might not support your intended (special) use case.

Answer (score 1):

As per [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/GeneratedValue.html) as well as [hibernate documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/GeneratedValue.html) though this annotation is specifically aimed for simple primary keys (as its elements are used to define primary key generator & strategy), I think you can still use this for non-primary key field provided you are not using any elements of this annotation.

But if you think of using generated value for non-primary key field, fetching records will be slower using this column as your predicate/ where clause.

In that case, you might need to impose index from database.
So using GeneratedValue for non-primary key may not be good practice.